# Exercicio básico JS: busca simples em texto

Tags: javascript

Estava tentando criar uma busca em JS para encontrar um nome dado no corpo de um texto. No entanto, a busca não retorna valor algum. A lógica que usei é:

```
<script>
var text = "Xxxxx, xxxx x xxxx x xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx. Lucas Menezes";
var myName = "Lucas";
var hits = [];
for (var x = 0; x < text.length; x = x + 1) {
    var adiction = myName.length + x;
    if (text[x] === "L") {
        if (text[adiction] === "s") {
            for (var i = x; i < adiction; i = i + 1) {
                hits.push(text[i]);
            };
        };
    };
};
if (hits.length === 0) {
    console.log("Your name wasn't found");
    console.log(adiction);
} else {
    console.log(hits);
    console.log(adiction);
}
</script>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar dizendo qual o problema? O *array* *hits* volta vazio. Caso retire o segundo `IF` ele até funciona, no entanto me retorna uma busca inexata apresentando qualquer nome que comece com `L` e os respectivos 4 caracteres posteriores.

Comment: Qual o resultado que você espera?

Comment: Esperava que o array hit me trouxesse: [L,u,c,a,s]

Comment: rsrsrs desculpa. Sou novo por aqui

Comment: Entendi, você precisa fazer isso desse jeito, ou um outro jeito serviria também?

Comment: Na verdade irmão, é somente um exercício básico, sou novo na programação. Se for possível desse modo, eu agradeço. Mas se achar outra forma conveniente para um iniciante. Já fico bastante agradecido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é nessa linha:

```
var adiction= myName.length + x;
```

Considerando que o índice começa de 0, em uma string de tamanho 5 você vai ter índices de 0 a 4. Portanto se você somar o tamanho da string você estará tentando acessar o índice 5.

Portanto é necessário subtrair 1 do seu índice final.

```
var adiction= myName.length + x - 1;
```

Comment: Apliquei o que me disse brother, e funcionou, no entanto me retornou [L,u,c,a]. Mas já serviu para que ele nao selecionasse outras palavras com L inicial.

Comment: Nesse caso, altere a linha "for(var i = x; i < adiction ; i = i + 1)" por "for(var i = x; i <= adiction ; i = i + 1)"

Comment: Exato! Obrigado fera! Só nao entendi porque caso retirasse o 2º condicional a busca me trazia resultado, e após ele, nem aparecia o resultado de "nao encontrado", ou qualquer erro de lógica, apenas o array vazio. Mas muito obrigado mesmo irmao.

Answer (score 9):

Você não precisa fazer essa busca "na unha", caractere por caractere. É mais fácil usar [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```js
var text = "Xxxxx, xxxx x xxxx x xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx. Lucas Menezes";
var myName= "Lucas";
var position = text.indexOf(myName);
console.log(position)
```

Também pode usar expressões regulares:

```js
var text = "Xxxxx, xxxx x Lucas x xxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx. Lucas Menezes";
var myName= "Lucas";
var re = new RegExp("(\\b" + myName + "\\b)", 'g')
var found = re.exec(text);
console.log(found)
```

Provavelmente na vida real você usaria uma dessas, ou a sugestão do Antonio Alexandre, e dificilmente varreria a string a cada caractere. Mas entendo que seja um exercício de programação, como você comentou numa das respostas. Nesse sentido é totalmente válido. O usuário dsmoreira já explicou bem qual era o problema. Só estou achando estranho que você queira guardar como resultado o próprio texto que buscou. Seria mais útil montar uma array assim:

```
[12, 27, ...]
```

Nesse caso, você guardaria a posição (inicial) onde cada ocorrência foi encontrada na string maior. Fica como sugestão.

Answer (score 3):

A pergunta já está respondida, mas para quem interessar possa segue uma outra forma de localizar elementos de texto usando string.search que pode ser adaptada para diferentes usos.

```html
<script>

texto_original = '';

window.onload=function()
{
 texto_original = document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML;
}

function busca()
{
 // Pega o conteúdo original da div com id = texto
 texto = texto_original;
 
 // Pega o termo que se quer buscar
 var termo_busca = document.getElementById("busca").value;
 
 var termo_len = termo_busca.length;
 
 var partes = new Array();
 
 partes_i = 0;

 //enquanto está achando termo_busca
 while(texto.search(termo_busca) != -1)
 {
  
  pos_proximo = texto.search(termo_busca);
  current_position = pos_proximo + termo_len;
    
  partes[partes_i] = texto.substring(0, pos_proximo); 

  //alert("Parte " + partes_i +": " + partes[partes_i]);  

  texto = texto.substring(current_position, texto.length);   
  
  //alert("Novo texto: " + texto);  
  
  partes_i = partes_i + 1;  


 }
 partes[partes_i] = texto;
 
  
 var glue = '<span class="destacado">' + termo_busca + '</span>';
 

 var novo_conteudo = partes.join(glue);

 
 document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = novo_conteudo;
 
}
</script>

<style>
.destacado { background-color:yellow;}
</style>



<input type="text" id="busca" value="Lucas"> <input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="busca()"> 

<br><br>

<div id="texto">
111 xxx xxx Lucas xxx xx222 xxxx xxxx Lucas xxxx 333x xxxx xxxx
</div>
```

Editado em 27/01/2017 às 17:08:

Segue agora uma outra forma de se fazer a mesma coisa que o código acima, só que usando replace do javascript. A diferença é que com replace se escreve menos código, mas não salva os pedaços, então esse código abaixo não dá tanta margem para modificações.

```html
<script>

texto_original = '';

window.onload=function()
{
 texto_original = document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML;
}


function busca_replace()
{
 // Pega o conteúdo original da div com id = texto
 texto = texto_original;
 
 // Pega o termo que se quer buscar
 var termo_busca = document.getElementById("busca").value;
 
 trocar_por = '<span class="destacado">' + termo_busca + '</span>';

 // criando expressão regular com a opção g e o termo_busca pra poder passar para o replace
 var regxp = new RegExp(termo_busca,"g"); 
 
 // Referência: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression
 
 texto = texto.replace(regxp,trocar_por);
 
 document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = texto;
}

</script>

<style>
.destacado { background-color:yellow;}
</style>


<input type="text" id="busca" value="Lucas"> <input type="button" value="Buscar" onclick="busca_replace()"> 

<br><br>

<div id="texto">
111 xxx xxx Lucas xxx xx222 xxxx xxxx Lucas xxxx 333x xxxx xxxx
</div>
```

Comment: Valew por compartilhar amigo! Bem útil essa sua sintaxe.

Comment: Valew Lucas, qualquer coisa só falar. A propósito vou incrementar a resposta com outro modo de fazer essa mesma busca para casos onde seja necessário apenas mudar o texto, usando suavariaveltexto.replace(procuraisso,mudapraisso) , passando no lugar de procuraisso uma expressão regular com a opção g para poder encontrar todas as ocorrências.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso te atende:

```js
var myText = "xxxx XXXX xxxx xxxx Junior Nunes";
var myName = 'Junior';


if(myText.indexOf(myName) != -1) {
  var hits = myName.split('');  
  console.log(hits);
}
else {
  console.log('O nome não foi encontrado');
}
```

O `indexOf` procura uma parte de texto dentro da string, se ele não encontrar ele retorna -1.

Caso encontre eu pego a variável `myName` que contém a string com o nome e divido todas as letras dentro de um array com o `split`.

Acho que essa é uma forma mais simples de entender...

OBS.: Caso fique com alguma dúvida comenta ai que eu te explico melhor!

**Editado**

Esse aqui é feito com for!!

```js
var myText = "xxxx XXXX xxxx xxxx Junior Nunes";
var myName = 'Junior';

var status = 'Não achou';

for(var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {
  if(myText[i] == myName[0]) {
    if(myText.substr(i, myName.length) == myName) {
      status = 'Achou';
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(status);
```

Comment: Legal cara. Funciona sim, no entanto acho que só posso utilizar as ferramentas que tenho até o momento. If...else / while / for... esses condicionais básicos. Mas fico muito agradecido pela ajuda fera. Com certeza vou anotar o index0f.

Comment: rsrsrsrs. Seu exemplo tem mais cara de busca de verdade (daí tu o destrói com o split!) para deixar no formato que pedi. KKK Acredito que o próximo passo seria justamente juntar a array em uma string. KKK Valeu mesmo brother!

Comment: @LucasMenezes Editei e coloquei um código usando for, mas acho o de cima mais simples mesmo...

Comment: Mas ele retorna "Achou". Além de utilizar substr que ainda nao ví. Mas nao se preocupa irmao o dsmoreira me mostrou como fazer uma pequena alteraçao naquela sintaxe inicial para que ele me retorne o que pedi. Mesmo assim valeu mesmo pela força.